# Db2 Stored Procedure results nothing

Tags: sql, db2

I am new to DB2 Development. I am trying to write a procedure that reads records from a file. Everything is going fine, but my procedure is not showing any results.

This is my code, I request you to please go through this & kindly correct me if I am wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REA_DT ()
LANGUAGE SQL
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE TB_NAME VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE EOF INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(500);

    -- Declare cursor
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN for 
    SELECT * FROM MT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET EOF=1;   
    -- Cursor left open for client application
    OPEN cursor1;
    WHILE EOF=0 
    DO 
    FETCH FROM cursor1 INTO TB_NAME;

    END  WHILE;
    CLOSE cursor1;
END P1
```

I don't know what to place after `FETCH` to display the variable value.
Thanks In advance

---

Now i can view all the records from my table. could you please let me know why this got happened. This is not my desired result. I am expecting to read records from the table on by one.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the cursor using `WITH RETURN`, indicating that you want the stored procedure to return a result set back to the application that calls the procedure.

But instead of simply issuing the `OPEN CURSOR` statement, you proceed to use the `WHILE` loop to read all rows from the cursor and then close the cursor.  Thus there is nothing returned to the application that called the stored procedure.

To return a cursor so the calling application can process the results from it, simply issue the `OPEN CURSOR` statement before the end of the procedure.  Do not `FETCH FROM` or `CLOSE` the cursor.